# Strange behavior when using lambda function on Pandas's groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with two groups `'A'` and `'B'`, and one element is missing in each of the group.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                    'X' : [0, 0.5,1, np.nan, 1,np.nan,1]})

Name    X
A       0.0
A       0.5
A       1.0
A       nan
B       1.0
B       nan
B       1.0
```

I would like to use a lambda function to fill in the missing data for each group

### Correct behavior when using `x.mean()`

```
df4.groupby('Name')['X'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
0    0.0
1    0.5
2    1.0
3    0.5 <------ Filled as 0.5
4    1.0
5    1.0 <------ Filled as 1
6    1.0
```

If I use `x.mean()` as shown above, the behavior is correct, since in group A, the mean is `1.5/3` which is `0.5`. The same goes for group B.

### Strange behavior when using `x.std()`

However, if I use `x.std()` instead, the filled number doesn't make sense to me. For group A, there's only three existing elements, `0`, `0.5`, and `1.0`, and their standard deviation should be `0.408`. Yet, the lambda function gives me the following output.

```
df4.groupby('Name')['X'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.std()))
0    0.0
1    0.5
2    1.0
3    0.5 <------ Filled as 0.5 instead of 0.4082
4    1.0
5    0.0 <------ Correct
6    1.0
```

Can anyone explain the behavior? Where does that 0.5 comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to change default parameter of [`pandas.Series.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html) `ddof=1` to `ddof=0`:

```
print (df4.groupby('Name')['X'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.std(ddof=0))))
0    0.000000
1    0.500000
2    1.000000
3    0.408248
4    1.000000
5    0.000000
6    1.000000
Name: X, dtype: float64
```